# Hard Fault on task switch with FreeRTOS on STM32

Tags: gcc, stm32, freertos

I'm moving my application from the Tiva TM4C123gh6pm (Cortex-M4) to STM32F446 (also Cortex-M4).

I use a common initialization routine for both and it works well for basic applications.

```
__attribute__(( naked ))
void ResetISR(void)
{

/*
 * This function is already started in Thread mode.
 * First the Control register will be set to use
 * the process stack.
 *
 * For more details about stacks, see page 2-2 of the DUI0553A
 * and page 74 of the Data Sheet.
 */

/*
 * Stack for the Thread Mode is selected by the ASP flag
 * of the Control register.
 *
 * For more details about the register, see
 * pp. 2-9 - 2.10 of the DUI0553A and
 * pp. 88 - 89 of the Data Sheet.
 */
__asm volatile("    MRS     r0, control         ");  /* r0 = control      */
__asm volatile("    ORR     r0, r0, #0x00000002 ");  /* r0 |= 2           */
__asm volatile("    MSR     control, r0         ");  /* control = r0      */
__asm volatile("    ISB                         ");  /* wait until synced */

/*
 * After the Thread Mode stack has been set,
 * its stack pointer must be set.
 */
__asm volatile("    LDR     r1, =_psp   ");   /* r1 = &_psp */
__asm volatile("    LDR     r0, [r1]    ");   /* r0 = *r1   */
__asm volatile("    MOV     sp, r0      ");   /* sp = r0    */
__asm volatile("    ISB                 ");


/*
 * Then initialize the BSS section.
 * Note that the BSS section may include the stack,
 * in this case initialization would also overwrite
 * local variables (in the stack), so the implementation
 * in C would probably not execute correctly. For this
 * reason, this task must be implemented in assembler.
 */

__asm volatile("    LDR     r0, =_bss        ");  /* r0 = &_bss             */
__asm volatile("    LDR     r1, =_ebss       ");  /* r1 = &_ebss            */
__asm volatile("    MOV     r2, #0           ");  /* r2 = 0                 */
__asm volatile("    .thumb_func              ");
__asm volatile("bss_zero_loop:               ");
__asm volatile("    CMP     r0, r1           ");  /* if (r0<r1)             */
__asm volatile("    IT      lt               ");  /* {                      */
__asm volatile("    STRLT   r2, [r0], #4     ");  /*   *(r0++) = r2         */
__asm volatile("    BLT     bss_zero_loop    ");  /*   goto bss_zero_loop } */

/*
 * Most likely the compiler will be able to
 * copy data initializers without pushing
 * these local variables to stack.
 */
uint32_t* src;
uint32_t* dest;

/*
 * Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM.
 */
src = &_etext;
for( dest = &_data; dest < &_edata; )
{
    *dest++ = *src++;
}

_init();
main();
}
```

However, once I use threads I get a hard fault.

```
void blinky(void *args) {

    printf("starting blinky\n");
    while (1) {
        DEFAULT_LED_TOGGLE;

        list_freertos_tasks();

        vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

(this is after the delay)

```
2015-11-30 18:59:11,722 - INFO # starting scheduler
2015-11-30 18:59:11,722 - INFO # starting blinky
2015-11-30 18:59:16,654 - INFO #    --|Hard Fault|-- 
2015-11-30 18:59:16,660 - INFO # r0:        0   r12: a5a5a5a5
2015-11-30 18:59:16,661 - INFO # r1: 20000fe4    lr:  8002263
2015-11-30 18:59:16,665 - INFO # r2: 10000000    pc:  80020de
2015-11-30 18:59:16,672 - INFO # r3: e000ed04   psr: 61000000
2015-11-30 18:59:16,672 - INFO # HFSR: 40000000 CFSR: 40000
```

I use the same compiler options for both.

```
CFLAGS += -mlittle-endian -mcpu=cortex-m4 -march=armv7e-m -mthumb
CFLAGS += -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard
```

Are there some subtle differences between TI's and ST's CM4 that I'm not aware of?

I also tried a compiling a different FreeRTOS project for the STM32F446-Nucleo that a colleague successfully created and ran with Keil.
It crashes with my `arm-none-eabi-gcc (15:4.9.3+svn227297-1) 4.9.3 20150529 (prerelease)` configuration.

(I previously used gcc 4.8.4 with the same result, I upgraded with the hope it might fix the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the bold red text on the following page that highlights an extra step necessary for STM32 parts: http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html

If that is the problem, then defining configASSERT() will catch it for you: http://www.freertos.org/a00110.html#configASSERT